# Using variables in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a problem in using variables in command prompt. Based on the value of the environment variable, i want to execute a few commands in a batch file. The code is below:

```
SET CONFIGURATION=Release

if "CONFIGURATION"=="Release"
(copy c:\python26\test1.py d:\testfiles
copy c:\case.jpg d:\images
)
else
(copy c:\python26\test2.py d:\testfiles
copy c:\debug.jpg d:\images
)
```

This is what I want to do. I am new to using these kind of scripts. So I don't have much information. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batch files have a somewhat special syntax

So your code should look like

```
SET CONFIGURATION=Release

if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="Release" (
  copy c:\python26\test1.py d:\testfiles
  copy c:\case.jpg d:\images
) else (
  copy c:\python26\test2.py d:\testfiles
  copy c:\debug.jpg d:\images
)
```

It's important, that the brackets are on the same line of `if`, `ELSE`

Answer (score 0):

When using the variable later, after set, you will surround the variable with percent signs, like so:

```
if %CONFIGURATION% == "release" ...
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel,Thanks for the help. but it does not seem to work for me. I did exactly this . SET configuration==release if %configuration%=="release" (echo success) else ( echo failure) . this printed failure :|